# Get ros params from parameter server

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, yaml, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 ROS nodes running sequentially from a script. Node1 sets some params in the parameter server which are to be used by node2. But node2 starts after node1 is killed. Currently I have a yaml config file where the dummy values of the params are saved and I load this file in the launch file. As soon as node1 starts I can see the params being updated in the server to new values. Node1 is killed and node2 starts. But node2 is using the dummy values set in yaml

How do I make sure node2 uses new values set by node1 in the parameter server?

using `rospy.set_param` to set the values in node1 and `rospy.get_param` in node2 to read the params

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380278/get-ros-params-from-parameter-server/) by [dee-mikey](https://answers.ros.org/users/69868/dee-mikey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-06-15**:\

> I have a yaml config file where the dummy values of the params are saved and I **load this file in the launch file.**

Can you edit your question to include that section of the launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch file will load the parameters before the nodes are started.  I had a similar issue where a System configurator node had to perform a calculation on some data at startup and post that before a second node could use it.

In my case I solved it by simply polling until the parameter had been updated.  Like this:

```
rospy.init_node('my_node_name', anonymous=False) 
 
# My normal parameter reads    

usb_media_poll_interval = rospy.get_param('/file_system/usb_media_poll_interval')

# My special parameter solution

system_node_id = 0

while system_node_id == 0: 
    system_node_id = rospy.get_param('/canbus/system_node_id')   # Thread will keep looping here until it is set

# Start the real work
```

In your case the '0' could be your dummy parameter.
You could also include a timeout if required

Alternatively you could just **not** set the dummy parameter in the yaml file and do something like:

```
while not rospy.has_param('your_parameter'):
    pass
```

Essentially you are creating a different state space for your node, one with the parameter set, and one without.  Therefore instead of a thread blocking while loop as I have used, you could have a simple `if rospy.has_param('your_parameter'):` branching down to a common `ros::spinOnce()` and `sleep()` if you wanted the node doing other things while waiting for the parameter

Another approach which is trivially implemented is to delay the launch of the node requiring the parameter using the launch_prefix tag.  This of course has the disadvantage of being less deterministic but effective.

```
<node name="yr_node" pkg="yr_pkg" type="yr_type" launch-prefix="bash -c 'sleep $(arg node_start_delay); $0 $@' " />
```

I first saw this delay mechanism posted by [kushlik](https://answers.ros.org/users/40140/kushlik/) and discussed [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/233353/set-delay-between-starting-nodes-within-launch-file/#316355)

Happy for criticism/suggestions/drawbacks as to these approaches by others

---

Originally posted by [James NT](https://answers.ros.org/users/43049/james-nt/) with karma: 36 on 2021-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0